# Image is not displaying as its size in Imageview widget

Tags: android, facebook

I got an image of size 960*540 pixels,but when I have imageview width and height to wrap_content,it is showing very small size.

I got posted pictures of facebook from facebook api,for example the url mentioned below
   https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/66547_4971955335921_1754998366_n.jpg
I used imageloader class to set this image to my imageview like I mentioned below

```
ImageView postimg= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picpost);
ImageLoader imageLoader;
imageLoader.DisplayImage(postimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), postimg) ;
```

And the xml I used is

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
        android:id="@+id/picpost"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

but I am getting very small image. I really can't understand why it is like this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In what lib did you put your image at? drawable-hdpi or what?

Comment: no its an image from facebook api and I am storing it in Arraylist and I am setting these images to imageview by using imageloader class.

Comment: did you try specific image size or match_parent instead of wrap_content?

Comment: Quick comment: postimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20") I would recommend URLEncoding this instead. It would make your code more robust

Comment: You may have to post your full code since this looks like it's in a RelativeLayout. The views in those can squish and expand other views. If you want the other views to respond to this guy, you can try to rig it as an anchor by placing it higher in the XML. How large is @+id/msg, and does that view exist?

Comment: I tried in another sample,I think the problem is with imageloader class.when I save the image and kept in drawable folder and I used android:src it is displaying image as same size,but it is not working when I used with imageloader class